# Dynamic DropDown in AngularJS "Full Calendar model popup"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angular js Full Calendar in Project and creating the events using angular js model popup, in popup dynamically i have to show Drop Down list to select....
and for popup i used 
            `<script type="text/ng-template"></script>`
 in html page. then the drop down values are not binding within the script tag. outside this script tag it is binding correctly but i want it within the script tag to work.... The below code in html page within the controller..

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header" style="color: white; background-color: #5bc0de;">
            <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Create Event</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Site : </label>
            <select id="ddlSites" ng-model="NewEvent.selectedSite" class="form-control" ng-options="item.SiteId as item.SiteName for item in sites">
         </select>
            </div>
```

Save

I tried all Possible ways, How to solve this..I am new to Angular JS...

Comment: You should provide your code for us in order to get help.

Comment: Please Help ..I Provided the code....